# Чистые виртуальные функции и чистый виртуальный деструктор обьявленные с пустым телом

Tags: c++

до сих пор я знал что  чистым виртуальным функциям не нужно тело, и обьявлять их даже с пустым телом, является ошибкой.
Мне недавно говорят обратное:

```
class A {
 public:
     ~A() = 0 {}
     //...
}
```

Что так не то что нельзя, но и нужно так обьявлять...

### Вопрос

Скажите пожалуйста, зачем чистой виртуальной функции тело? Тело чего? Где смысль чистой виртуальности тогда? И в конце концов, если это правда, почему тогда мой компилятор выдает ошибку? Это что то новое после C++14?..

Вот ошибка моего компилятора:

```
C:\Users\Mk\Documents\H\C++\test\main.cpp:12: error: pure-specifier on function-definition virtual ~A() = 0 {}
```

Comment: Где здесь виртуальность?

Comment: Извеняюсь, исправил

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652198/difference-between-a-virtual-function-and-a-pure-virtual-function) хорошее описание.

Comment: Вполне можно найти аргументы в пользу разрешения определения для чистой функции - в С++ нет возможности просто объявить класс абстрактным. Достаточно рядовая ситуация, когда класс должен быть абстрактным, но все функции в нем имеют реализацию. Вот тут и поможет чистая функция с определением (хотя на мой взгляд введение ключевого слова abstract было бы лучшим решением). Но вот деструктор делать чистым не стоит вообще. Это все-таки не совсем обычная функция, и программист не вполне контролирует его вызовы. Опять же на мой взгляд, лучше было бы вообще запретить чистые деструкторы.

Comment: @freim: Совершенно верно. Именно в такой ситуации считается, что деструктор - самый лучший кандидат на эту "фиктивную" чистоту (т.е. чистоту только ради того, чтобы сделать класс абстрактным). Ибо деструктор всегда есть и, в случае наследования, обычно виртуален.

Comment: @AnT: Это как раз тот случай, когда нужда выдается за добродетель. У языка отсутствует нормальная возможность объявить класс абстрактным, и начинаются мутные трюки с объявлением чистыми функций, которые имеют реализацию, и ни с какой стороны чистыми не являются. Ну а чистый деструктор это просто какое-то извращение, уж лучше базовый класс оставить неабстрактным, чем такое городить. Вообще С++ это типичный комитетский язык, и это очень сказывается. Прямо по известной поговорке, что верблюд - это лошадь, разработанная комитетом.

Comment: @freim: Существуют и другие способы "заабстрактить" класс в С++. Например, сделать все конструкторы `protected`.

Comment: @AnT: Да, часто именно так и делаю. Уж во всяком случае это лучше, чем определять чистую функцию. По крайней мере тут сразу понятно, что класс не инстанцируется. А определение "чистой" функции, зарытое где-то в глубинах cpp, это такая подлянка от разработчика тому, кто будет потом разбираться с кодом. Не сразу ведь и поймешь в чем дело.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Формально в 10.4.2 есть замечание-

> Объявление функции не может содержать одновременно чистый-спецификатор и описание функции. ■
>
> Пример.
>   `struct C
>   { 
>       virtual void f() = 0 { }; // неправильно 
>   };`
>   Конец примера.

Но при этом ее можно определять:

> Описывать чистую виртуальную функцию необходимо только в случае, когда она вызывается посредством синтаксиса квалифицированного-идентификатора (5.1), или похожим образом (12.4).

Т.е., похоже, что чисто виртуальная функция может быть определена, но только не в объявлении.

Comment: Точку с запятой нужен?..

Comment: Ну, я дал так, как приведено :)

Comment: еще один вопрос:  вообше  правильно ли деструктор перечислять (назвать)  к функциям?

Comment: "*Не вижу препятствий*" (с) Вызывается как функция, синтаксис имеет функции... Что еще нужно?

Comment: больше ничего не нужно,  я тоже так понимал, но так как  я  все таки изучал язык чисто самостоятельно, решил спросить об этом  вам. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Вы не поверите, но, так сказать, официально, в универе, я учил только один язык - Алгол :) И то, поскольку обещали нас учить Фортрану (поменяли в самый последний момент), с Алголом я для себя лично перед этим на каникулах старательно ознакомился :)

Comment: я специалист по строительным и дорожным машинам, и в универе изучал только  начальное представление о битах и  бейсик(к тому же я  ВТ
 прогуливал в основном), и то это было далеко в 80 - х годах... Так что я в свои 53 являюсь чистым новычком в программировании(хобби)

Answer (score 5):

Если функция является pure virtual, то попытка *виртуального* вызова такой функции приводит к неопределенному поведению. На этом факте основана популярное верование в то, что у pure virtual функции не может/не должно быть тела.

Однако язык предоставляет средства для прямого (*невиртуального*) вызова виртуальных функций через указание квалифицированного имени метода

```
some_object_ptr->SomeClass::some_method();
```

Таким способом можно вызывать виртуальные функции напрямую, без использования механизмов виртуального вызова. Таким способом можно спокойно вызывать и pure virtual функции. При этом если у вызываемой pure virtual функции нет определения (нет тела), то это будет являться таким же нарушением ODR, как и для обычных функций.

(Вопрос во многом аналогичен вопросу о том, могут ли вызовы виртуальных функций быть встроенными (inlined)).

---

Деструктор класса - функция особая. Деструктор класса-предка всегда неявно вызывается напрямую из деструкторов классов-потомков. Поэтому если у класса-предка есть хотя бы один инстанциируемый в программе класс-потомок, то деструктору класса-предка обязательно нужно определение. Является ли этот деструктор pure virtual или не является - значения не имеет.

---

Выдаваемая вашим компилятором ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к теме наличия или отсутствия тела у pure virtual функции. Ошибка выдается из-за того, что в С++ не существует синтаксиса для определения pure virtual функции прямо в теле класса. Такие функции надо определять отдельно, за пределами класса.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, инстанциация абстрактного класса невозможна, соответственно невозможен и виртуальный вызов чистой функции, поскольку она гарантированно переопределена. Единственный способ ее вызвать - это прямой вызов по квалифицированному имени. О какой "попытке виртуального вызова" вы говорите (и чего я не понимаю)?

Comment: @freim: Вы почти правы. Сделать *виртуальный* вызов чистой функции "почти невозможно" именно по этой причине. Но есть одна лазейка: вызов во время работы конструктора или деструктора абстрактного класса (через промежуточный метод). Допустим конструктор вызывает промежуточный метод `foo()`, а он уже виртуально вызывает чистую функцию `bar()`. Если вызвать `foo()` из конструктора абстрактного класса - то произойдет виртуальный вызов чистой функции. Смотрите: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/100bad983d8eba76